# Google Appengine Shutdown and Startup Scripts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, memcached

Any java code suggestion to manually add startup and shutdown scripts in google app engine before and after deployment to persist local cache

Comment: can you please explain your query in more detail?

Comment: i need to write a shutdown script in java so that when ever appengine is going to down the instance all my local cache should be restored to datastore or some files in server

Comment: Register a `shutdown` hook: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown

Answer (score 1):

You can use “Shutdown Hook” to know when your instance will go down but it’s unreliable
as it’s specified in the  [Official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown).

You can use [memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/) for App Engine, in this way you don’t have to care about your instance because the cache will persist even the instance goes down.

You can use memcache as a shared cache instead of a local cache. [Using Memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/memcache/using)

Note that memcache is for First Generation [Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes) , otherwise for Second Generation Runtimes you can use [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/).

There is a tutorial for Memorystore [How to Connect Google Cloud Memorystore with App Engine Standard](https://medium.com/@the.hasham.ali/how-to-connect-google-cloud-memorystore-with-app-engine-standard-b76569ef79e2)